# The proper usage of 'compeer'; and is it a root word?

Tags: word-usage, suffixes, roots

Compeer has a definition:

A person of equal rank, status or ability

What I am asking is what context is this word typically used? And equally important - is it valid to use the words compeering and compeeringly? What is the general rule for this?

I'd really like to use the word compeering, but I'm not sure how correct it would be to.

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=compeer%2Cpeer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccompeer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpeer%3B%2Cc0) reinforce my belief that I'm in good company never using it.

Comment: It is not typically used. At all. The real question is, what is wrong with "peer"?

Comment: Even supposing that "compeer" was a common word that you might use in sentences like, "He and his compeers went out to dinner after the presentation." or "I know Ed. He is a compeer of mine." and noticing that I can substitute *peer* for *compeer* in all those sentences.  Give me a sentence in which you would use "peering" (where it doesn't mean *looking intently at something*).

Comment: Well, okay. "In order to beat oppression, one must face oppression through the eyes of the oppressed as can only be done by those that take the peering journey into their minds" EDIT: This is assuming you meant to replace compeering with peering in the context of you not seeing a meaningful difference between peer and compeer.

Comment: @Jaico What would "compeering" mean exactly? What would "peeringly" or "compeeringly" mean?

Comment: @MattSamuel It would mean that the journey is taken within the context of the two individuals (the one taking the journey and the person who's mind the journey is exploring) are equal in status, or compeers/peers.

Comment: @Jaico It just doesn't make sense. It's like saying "microphoningly" or "chairingly," or maybe "grassingly" or "doorknobbingly."

Answer (score 1):

It's not good style to us words of the rarest frequency. For me it is a dictionary corpse or carcass, that is registered in the dictionary but not used. If you use it you may be sure that nobody has heard of the word.

Answer (score 0):

Compeering is a word so far as SCRABBLE players are concerned. It's in the official SCRABBLE dictionary put out by Merriam-Webster and is a verb meaning to equal or to match.

http://scrabble.merriam.com/finder/compeer

If you like it use it.